# Setting package.json defaults

Tags: json, node.js, package, npm

I want to set few `package.json` property defaults.

For example, most of my libraries published on NPM, have the `MIT` license. Also, I am the author of most of them (sometimes the author is the company I work for).

How can I set such defaults?

I expect the following behavior:

```shell
$ npm init
...
author: (Ionică Bizău)
license: (MIT)
...
```

So, just pressing enter will set the default values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To see npm configuration, run:

```
npm config list
```

which typically will contain such

```
userconfig /home/scott/.npmrc
```

cat above file to see all your overrides

```
npm config ls -l #  to show all defaults
```

you can manually define defaults

```
npm config edit  # view then change all settings
```

alternatively you can interactively set defaults :

```
npm set init.author.name "<Your Name>"
npm set init.author.email "you@example.com"
npm set init.author.url "example.com"
npm set init.license "MIT"
```

each set has a corresponding get

Answer (score 1):

Use [npmrc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc) to set your defaults.

Comment: How? Can you detail your answer?

Comment: @IonicăBizău Set the value for the key `init.author.name` to what you wish. You can find a list of keys npm understands in the man page for `npm-config`. There 's a link for it at the bottom of the page I 've linked to in my answer.